# Mixing programmatic and declarative transactions in legacy software

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My question concerns about possible concurrency issues with mixing programmatic and declarative transactions. I am developing a legacy software (Spring + Hibernate) that handles database connections and transactions in a programmatic fashion.

```
Session db = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
db.beginTransaction();
// do stuff
db.getTransaction().commit();
```

The software has newer modules that are using Spring data architecture with declarative transactions (@Transactional). We have experienced database deadlocks in rare cases with Microsoft SQL Server when newer Spring services are being called from inside "manually" opened transactions. I think the problem is that there are two nested transactions reading/writing same tables causing deadlocks.

```
Session db = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
db.beginTransaction();
// do stuff
springService.getStuff();
// do stuff
db.getTransaction().commit();
```

Is there a way to mix these transactions safely or use the already started transaction in both? Should I just close the manually/programmatically opened transaction before calling Spring @Service/@Repository methods? Both Spring and HibernateUtil uses the same entity manager for database connections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When it comes to the behavior of the transactions, there is really no difference between declarative and programmatic/manual ones. Declarative transactions enable you to demarcate transaction boundaries in a more concise and readable way, that's all about it. Under the hood, Spring will do the same thing you would do manually to start and commit/rollback transactions.

> I think the problem is that there are two nested transactions
>   reading/writing same tables causing deadlocks.

Very possible.

> Is there a way to mix these transactions safely or use the already
>   started transaction in both?

Whether it is safe to do it in your specific part code highly depends on what the code does. If a nested transaction will cause deadlock, then it's obviously not safe, and that has nothing to do how you obtained the nested transaction (manually or Spring started it when intercepting a method annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW)`).

> Should I just close the manually/programmatically opened transaction
>   before calling Spring `@Service`/`@Repository` methods?

Again, depends of what you need to solve. If you need the outer transaction to proceed once the nested transaction completes, then you shouldn't. Otherwise you can.

[TransactionTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) is the recommended way to manually start transactions with Spring, because Spring is then aware of transaction boundaries, meaning it will treat such a transaction the same as if it were started declaratively with a Spring annotation.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to propagate a manually started transaction to Spring @Transactional methods?

Comment: @anssias You can take a look at [`TransactionTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html). If you start your transaction that way, it will work, because Spring will be aware of the transaction.

Comment: That looks more like what I was looking for. Can you add that to your answer and I will accept it as an anwser. Thank you!